# LoadLibrary GetProcAddress - why does this work?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, loadlibrary, getprocaddress

When I run this code with Visual Studio Code with the function name `"MessageBoxA"`, it works, and it provides me a pointer to the function.

However, when I change the name of the function to, for example, `"MessageBoxATEST"` and save it, it still provides me the same function address.

How is that possible (since this function does not exist in `user32.dll`)?

When I change, for example, the name of the DLL to `User32TEST.dll`, it gives me the error `Function not loaded ....` , as it should.

Can anybody help?

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef BOOL(*func_pointer)(LPSTR, LPCSTR);
int main () {

    HMODULE Handle_DLL = LoadLibrary("User32.dll");
    func_pointer Pointer = (func_pointer)(Handle_DLL,"MessageBoxATEST");

    if (Handle_DLL == NULL || Pointer == NULL){
        DWORD error = GetLastError();
        printf("Function not loaded into memory %d\n", error);
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        printf("Function address: %p\n", (void*)Pointer);
        FreeLibrary(Handle_DLL);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

> with the function name `"MessageBoxA"` it does work and it provides me a pointer to the function

No, it doesn't.

> when I change the name of the function to for example `"MessageBoxATEST"` and save it, it still provides me the same function address

It never was a function address.

You forgot to actually call `GetProcAddress`.  What you have now is (after considering the behavior of the comma operator) `(func_pointer)"MessageBoxATest"` which is clearly not a NULL pointer.

Comment: My bad for some reason I forgot to add getprocaddress, now I did add this and it works, and when I make MessageBoxTEST then it doesnt work, as it should. thanks